# Can't call this inside arrow function

Tags: javascript, angular, function, typescript, ionic-framework

I have problem when i'm trying to access by `this` keyword. I need to access `run` function inside `updateTime`

```
export class PlayerService {

 createPlayer(): void {
            return new window['YT'].Player(this.youtube.playerId, {
                height: this.youtube.playerHeight,
                width: this.youtube.playerWidth,

                events: {
                    'onStateChange': (event) => {

                        function updateTime() {

                   //////I need to access | run function | from here 

                        };

                        this.timeupdater = setInterval(updateTime, 100);


                    }
                }
            });
        }

           run (){

    //some codes 



                }
}
```

I'm working on ionic 2

Comment: Can you update your question to show all the code and the failure?

Comment: Make sure to use an arrow function for `updateTime` as well

Comment: @Bergi yes that was the problem , I have no idea about this before ( the problem is I have to use arrow in both )  , but i didnt understand how this is could be duplicated question ?  there is nothing related from your marking question :)

Comment: @programmer Of course it is. It explains (all the ways) how to access the `this` value inside a function like `updateTime` that you pass as a callback to something (`setTimeout` in your example), and why it doesn't work with `function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go arrow function all the way

```
function updateTime() {
```

should be

```
var updateTime = () => {
```

or

```
setInterval(updateTime, 100);
```

should be

```
setInterval(() => updateTime(), 100);
```

Comment: I got syntax error

Comment: Please post the exact and full error.

Comment: Try my updated answer.

Comment: you are amazing  thank you so much  .  I didnt understand why they marked as duplicate question after 10 second of posting the question  .

Comment: Glad to hear you could make it work. There are already about 5k questions about the same issue, therefore some people lose patience ;-)

Comment: "and" should be "or"